# Internet explorer 9 gives parseJSON error

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-9, jquery-1.9

I don't know if it's caused by jQuery or by my script. This is where internet explorer 9 gives error:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data ); <<< this the "Invalid Character" err.
    }
```

This is my javascript code

http://jsfiddle.net/fNPwh

From my research I also checked out my DOCTYPE here it is. They were talking about Quirks mode so I also tried to put `x-ua-compatible` but nothing changed

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > <!-- IE9 mode -->
blabla
```

Why ie9 gives jQuery's invalid character error? and not the firefox or webkit. Oh by the way I am using jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why not just set the `dataType` for the `post()` request to `json` and let jQuery handle the parsing?

Comment: Can you show me an example? I am using my data like 'x.name,x.page...'

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ I looked into dataType and thats cool now I don't need to use parseJSON but I still wonder why IE gave error :D

Comment: I made the example but in the meantime you figured it out - here's the link in case others are interested: http://jsfiddle.net/mbrowne/jqbUp/. As to IE giving an error, it might be more strict about following the JSON spec than other browsers you were testing in. It could have been that the keys of your JSON object weren't surrounded by quotes, but it's hard to say without seeing your JSON.

Comment: http://paste.laravel.com/jTl -> this is my JSON

Comment: Maybe the date was throwing it off? What's some example output of `json_encode`?

Comment: Likely a trailing comma: `{ a:"b", c:"d", }` will make IE unhappy

Comment: http://paste.laravel.com/jTn
this is what I get on json. For another problem is my $.post not fires callback or $.post not even firing on IE, I can't debug since F12 in IE not loves developers :D

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the jQuery library. [This post](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13430) contains code to add/modify for the fix. Basically just move the check for `null` before the attempt to parse and add a check for `undefined`. The start of the method should then look like this...

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    if (data === undefined) {
        return data;
    }
    if (data === null) {
        return data;
    }

    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }
...
```

I've verified this fix in IE10 and Chrome.